# How to open host address using host name?

Tags: apache, xampp, host

I am trying to open my host address using my host name, but I am getting following error:

[image]

You can see the host URL above.
Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: The image is too small...

Comment: do i need to upload again?

Comment: HI @vbmaster I uploaded high res image then before.
Please check and give solution

Comment: As the page says, you need to modify `httpd-xampp.conf` to allow localhost to access your `/xampp` folder.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states you cannot access it outside you local network. In another words - your apache xampp is configured to accept calls only from 127.0.0.1 or localhost. For xampp this is defined in location match directive for apache look at the following topic, it covers the most common cases. Note however that this might be security issue.

http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=185823

This will provide you more info on how allow and deny can be configured
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow

Something like this should be in your httpd-xampp.conf

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 **your.local.ip.address**
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```